# Ubuntu 20.4 Settings opens slow, battery indicator disappeared, power statistics won't open

Tags: 20.04, battery, settings

I have 3 issues that I suspect are related.

The Power and Displays pages in settings take 5 to 10 seconds to load
The battery indicator in the upper right corner is missing.
Power Statistics refuses to open.

I've reinstalled gnome-control-center and the ubuntu-desktop.

Gnome Tweaks has the option to show the battery indicator but it does nothing. On boot there is an open space for it in the top bar and drop down.

All packages are upgraded

Comment: The settings app (gnome-control-center) does start very slowly for me too. The graphs of the system monitor shell extension show that it spends a lot of time reading from the disk before its window appears.